# execl() arguments in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, exec

I am learning linux programming and came across exec function which is kind of very useful. But the problem is exec function arguments are very confusing and I am unable to grasp which argument is for what purpose.. In the following code `execl()` function is called from a child created through `fork()`, What is the purpose of the last argument (`NULL`) in `execl()`?

```
execl("/bin/ls","ls","-l",NULL);
```

If any one can explain what is the purpose of `NULL` argument and other arguments and the purpose of arguments of `exec()` family function, It would be a great help to me!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To create undefined behavior.  That is not a legal call to `execl`.  A
correct call might be:

```
execl( "/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", (char*)0 );
```

The last argument *must* be `(char*)0`, or you have undefined behavior.
The first argument is the path of the executable.  The following 
arguments appear in `argv` of the executed program.  The list of these
arguments is terminated by a `(char*)0`; that's how the called function
knows that the last argument has been reached.  In the above example,
for example, the executable at `"/bin/ls"` will replace your code; in
its `main`, it will have `argc` equal 2, with `argv[0]` equal `"ls"`,
and `argv[1]` equal `"-l"`.

Immediately after this function, you should have the error handling
code.  (`execl` always returns -1, when it returns, so you don't need to
test it.  And it only returns if there was some sort of error.)

Comment: Why exactly do you think that using `NULL` instead of `(char*)0` creates undefined behaviour?

Comment: @JanSpurny Because the Posix standard says so.  More generally, the C standard says that it is undefined behavior if a varargs function tries to extract a type other than the type which was passed.  `execl` is documented to require a `char*`.  It could hardly try for another type until it had extracted the argument.  `NULL` has an integral type, usually `int`.  So passing `NULL` is undefined behavior, and has been ever since pointers stopped being ints.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Utter bullshit. POSIX states that `NULL`, as a null pointer, *is zero converted to a pointer* [POSIX definitions, 3.244], usually `(void *)0`. It **is** either `(void *)0`, or an equivalent expression. In C89 and C99, `void *` does not need to be cast to any other pointer type. Therefore -- and this encompasses **ALL** C89/C99/GNU C implementations I've ever used, from microcontrollers to computational clusters -- `NULL` is the correct one to use for this, and all other similar variadic functions.

Comment: @NominalAnimal `NULL` isn't a null pointer, it's a null pointer constant.  And a null pointer constant is required by the C++ standard to have an integral type.  I've only seen two definitions of `NULL` in Unix: `0` and g++'s `__null` compiler magic.  It is _always_ an error to pass `NULL` to a variadic function where pointers are expected.  The Posix standard specifies using `(char*)0`, and the Linux man pages explicitly state that `NULL` must be passed as `(char*)NULL`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Just to be perfectly clear, when `NULL` (or `0`) is used in a context which requires a pointer type, it is implicitly converted to a null pointer.  Passing an argument to a `...` does _not_ require a pointer type, however, and no conversion occurs; you pass `0`.  G++ uses compiler magic for `NULL`, so you'll probably get away with it with g++, but I've used more than a few compilers where it wouldn't work; where `char*` was larger than an `int` (and `NULL` was defined as `0`).

Answer (score 4):

The `exec` functions are variadic: they take a variable number of parameters so that you can pass a variable number of arguments to the command. The functions need to use `NULL` as a marker to mark the end of the argument list.

Within variadic functions is a loop that will iterate over the variable number of arguments. These loops need a terminating condition. In some cases, e.g. `printf`, the actual number of arguments can be inferred from another argument. In other functions, `NULL` is used to mark the end of the list.

Another option would be to add an additional function parameter for *number of arguments*, but that would make the code a little more brittle, requiring the programmer to manage an additional parameter, rather than simply always using a `NULL` as the final argument.

You'll also see `(char *) 0` used as the marker:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", (char *) 0);
```

Comment: Both the number _and_ the type of the arguments have to agree with what the called function expects.  How the called function knows what to expect is documented.  In the case of `execl`, the called function expects a list of `char*`, terminated by a null pointer of type `char*`.  Since `NULL` has type `int` (or at least an integral type), passing it here is undefined behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze again you and your undefined behaviors ...

Answer (score 1):

In `/usr/include/libio.h`, since gcc 2.8 (a long time ago) `NULL` is defined to be **null (** is reserved for builtins), prior to that `NULL` was `(void *)0` which is indistinguishable from `(char *)0` in a `varargs` situation since the type is not passed, the exception being if `__cplusplus` is defined in which case `NULL` is defined as 0.

The safe thing to do especially if you have a 64-bit architecture is to explicitly use `(void *)0` which is defined to be compatible with any pointer and not rely on any dodgy `#defines` that might happen to be in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

The **purpose** of the ending argument `(char *) 0` is to terminate the parameters. Undefined behavior may result if this is missing.
The man page defines the **execl** signature as :

```
int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);
```

*path*: The location of the program to invoke, the program to invoke.

*arg*, ...*: can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn.

In your case `execl( "/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", (char*)0 );` is the correct function call.

"*bin/ls*" the program to invoke

"*ls*" the program name

"*-l*" is the parameter for that program called

Answer (score 0):

The glibc-2.34 implementation of the POSIX `execl` function looks like this below.

```
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <stddef.h>

/* Execute PATH with all arguments after PATH until
   a NULL pointer and environment from `environ'.  */
int
execl (const char *path, const char *arg, ...)
{
  ptrdiff_t argc;
  va_list ap;
  va_start (ap, arg);
  for (argc = 1; va_arg (ap, const char *); argc++)
    {
      if (argc == INT_MAX)
    {
      va_end (ap);
      errno = E2BIG;
      return -1;
    }
    }
  va_end (ap);

  /* Avoid dynamic memory allocation due two main issues:
     1. The function should be async-signal-safe and a running on a signal
        handler with a fail outcome might lead to malloc bad state.
     2. It might be used in a vfork/clone(VFORK) scenario where using
        malloc also might lead to internal bad state.  */
  ptrdiff_t i;
  char *argv[argc + 1];
  va_start (ap, arg);
  argv[0] = (char *) arg;
  for (i = 1; i <= argc; i++)
    argv[i] = va_arg (ap, char *);
  va_end (ap);

  return __execve (path, argv, __environ);
}
libc_hidden_def (execl)
```

The first loop computes `argc`, the number of arguments to `execl` (including the first argument, `path`). The condition of the first loop is `va_arg (ap, const char *)`. If you use `0` as the last argument, the macro will expand to something like:

```
const char* temp = 0;
...
return temp;
```

Any scalar zero value assigned this way is false. So using `0` as the last argument will terminate the loop.

The second loop forms the `argc`-length array of arguments, `argv`. Note each argument is explicitly casted to `char*` on assignment. In the case of `0` as the last argument, the resulting value in `argv` from the macro expansion will be as though you'd written:

```
char* p = 0;
argv[i] = p;
...
```

Again, this is definitely a zero value, and will evaluate to false in the loop condition within execve. Unpopular opinion, but using `0` as the last argument in `execl` is technically correct. You don't have to stress about the `int (32-bit) -> char* (64-bit)` "it's implementation and might not pad with zeroes" conversion b.s., because va_arg is a macro - it *defines* a `char*` on the spot and assigns `0` to it, which guarantees it will have a false logical value.

Answer (score 0):

The "NULL" represents the termination of the the commands.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers.