# Does `execl` need NULL as last parameter?

Tags: c, linux

The man page of my linux (Ubuntu), does not mention the need of NULL as last parameter, the man page of a minix version `execl` mentions the need of NULL as last parameter. Yet, I had strange behavior while invoking `modprobe` that I solved putting NULL as last parameter.

The way that worked for me:

```
execl("/sbin/modprobe","modprobe","pl2303",NULL);
```

While if I do it this way:

```
execl("/sbin/modprobe","modprobe","pl2303")
```

I get an error no 14 (EFAULT).`

Comment: Check your man page again.

Comment: Apart from what the man page says, think about it: `execl` needs to have *some* way to detect the end of the argument list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The man page on my Linux does say it explicitly:

> The  const  char *arg and subsequent ellipses in the execl(),
>   execlp(), and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ...,
>   argn.
>   [....]
>
> **The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer**, and, since
>   these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.

With all due respect to Linux and Minix, the more authoritative page I think is the one from [opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html), which says:

> The arguments represented by arg0,... are pointers to null-terminated
>   character strings. These strings shall constitute the argument list
>   available to the new process image. **The list is terminated by a null
>   pointer**.

Comment: I though it was refering just to the execv version of the command. But know I see it repeats this statement in the execl paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument is the path of the executable and the following arguments are actually the `argv` of the executed program. The list of these arguments is terminated by a `(char*)0`

Citing from the man page:

> The list of
>          arguments must be terminated by a null pointer, and, since these are
>          variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.

Also references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12677236/1938163 , http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does, the ISO C standard mandates for `main` that `argv[argc]` should be NULL to allow for programs to either use `argc` or a sentinel at the end, and the same reasoning applies to the `exec`-like calls.

The POSIX docs for this can be found at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html and they state:

> The argv and environ arrays are each terminated by a null pointer. The null pointer terminating the argv array is not counted in argc.